# How to authenticate to Office365 from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cordova, office365

How can I authenticate to Office365 and make REST requests to SharePoint Online using the Office365 API in JavaScript pages not using Visual Studio 2013. I would like to make the calls using Cordova/PhoneGap.

Which files do I need to include in JS and what type of methods needs to be called.

PS: I can't create a new Office365APIs tag for posts.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the Problem by using Basic Authentication. I don't know which library you use, so for JQuery it would look something like this.

```
$.getJSON({
'url': 'https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/OData/Me/Events',
'beforeSend': function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authentication",
        "Basic " + encodeBase64(username + ":" + password)
},
success: function(result) {
    alert('done');
}
```

});

I actually don't use a certain API from Microsoft, I wrote all requests by my own.

Answer (score 0):

Although you say "not using Visual Studio 2013" I am guessing that you mean you want to use JavaScript and Cordova. You can do this using Visual Studio 2015 (or Visual Studio 2013 with the Apache Cordova Tools add-on) by building a Blank Cordova app and then using Add Connected Service to add the Office 365 API. This will install a number of JavaScript files in your project, including the authorization components which amongst other things will enable you to obtain an access token which you can use with REST calls.

```
var authContext = new O365Auth.Context();
authContext.getIdToken("https://outlook.office365.com/").then(function (token) {
        token.getAccessToken('https://outlook.office365.com').then(function (accessToken) {
                    var bearerToken = "Bearer " + accessToken;
                    $.ajax(someOffice365RequestUri, {
                        headers: {
                            "Authorization": bearerToken,
                            "Accept": "application/json;odata.metadata=minimal"
                        }
                    }).then(function (response) {
                          // do stuff with response data...
                    });
```

Once you have everything in place you can of course choose to do your development using whatever tooling you like.